# Apply only to IE 11 within media query for screen size

Tags: css, media-queries, internet-explorer-11

I currently have following width specific media query.

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 1920px) {
    .toggleMultiSelect .filter {
        width: 566px;
    }
 }
```

But the width for '**.toggleMultiSelect .filter**' changes in IE from Chrome/Firefox. So basically need to apply different width for the same css class in 1920px for IE. From the Stackoverflow search I found that IE specific behavior can be achieved like below.

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
    .toggleMultiSelect .filter {
        width: 575px;
    }
}
```

So now I need to achieve both resolution and css class. **575px** width only should apply to IE and Chrome or firefox should get **566px**.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use the below css inside the media query

**IE 10 and above**

```
_:-ms-lang(x), .ie10up { 
       property:value; 
    }
```

**IE 11 and above**

```
_:-ms-fullscreen, :root .CLASS_NAME { 
       property:value; 
     }
```

Comment: Hi Shahil, it should be like this right?
`@media only screen and (max-width: 1920px) {
    _:-ms-fullscreen, :root .ie11up .toggleMultiSelect .filter{
        width: 575px;
    }
}`
I tried this, but no luck.

Comment: @Luke its should be  _:-ms-fullscreen, :root .toggleMultiSelect .filter {  width: 566px;  }

Comment: `_:-ms-lang(x),` the "magic" term which solves the problem. `.ie10up` is just misleading. It should be `.toggleMultiSelect .filter` to be responsive to the question asked.

Answer (score 5):

**Did you try combining them like this -**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1920px) {
    .toggleMultiSelect .filter {
        width: 566px;
    }
    @media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
       .toggleMultiSelect .filter {
         width: 575px;
       }
    }

 }
```

This may work am **Not** sure, am using `Mac` so no way to test, But I think this will work for you. Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Hi weBer, I have tried this. But in IE it's the 566px width applied still. Not the 575px. Thank you for the response.

Comment: @Luke is the second style coming when you inspect the class.? if it is we can try using `!important` in the style.

Comment: adding important didn't work also. Appreciate the help. Thank you